# Asynchronous tasks when node server.close() invoked

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on an node+express application and want to prepare it to make a graceful. The goal is to make deployments in the "right" way, that is:

- Avoid accepting requests
- Finish the current ones
- Terminate node process
- Put new code
- Restart server-

For the graceful shutdown I'm using a code similar to:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(1337);

process.on( 'SIGTERM', function () {

   server.close(function () {
     console.log( "Closed out remaining connections.");
     // Close db connections, etc.
     //
     // How to ensure no tasks is running in the thread pool ???
   });

   setTimeout( function () {
     console.error("Could not close connections in time, forcefully shutting down");
     process.exit(1); 
   }, 30*1000);

});
```

My doubt is to know if inside `server.close()` **can I be sure no task is running or pending execution ?**

What happens if a job in the event loop started reading a big file asynchronously and is working in the thread pool? **Does `server.close` warranties no tasks are running in the thread pool too?**

Comment: Do you really need to do it by yourself ? because you can run your app with pm2 and it already handle graceful restart, clustering and many other feature.

Comment: What you mean by `How to ensure no tasks is running in the thread pool`?

Comment: @stdob suppose there is a request that requires get some data from database. That async task is made in a thread pool and notified to my single thread of execution via callback. What happens with that tasks if I made a shutdown???

Comment: #mJehanno pm2 also requires your app to listen for the SIGNINT event. It does not make the shutdown for you

Comment: @EricSonaron I use the critical task counter: when the critical task starts - the counter increases, when the task finishes - the counter decreases. Also critical tasks before starting to check if the "maintenance" flag is set: if set, they do not start until "restart".